# Error defining function in test using Jest with Typescript

Tags: typescript, function, types, jestjs

I am starting a new project in nodejs with typescript, and I am stuck with a problem while testing arrow function.

The code is the following, in typescript.

(Actual code is more complex and I use arrow functions for a purpose, but this reproduces my problem)

Please note the type defined inside the function.

```js
describe('Test function', () => {
    test('Arrow function', () => {
        const myFunction = (x: number) => x + 1 // <=== Please note the type
        expect(myFunction(3)).toBe(4);
    });
});
```

The problem arises while running jest at compile time, and I receive the following error:

```
 FAIL  src/myTest.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: /Users/ettoregalli/Documents/SVILUPPO/nodejs/node-fun-ts/src/chain.test.ts: Unexpected token, expected "," (14:29)

      12 |     test('Arrow function', () => {
      13 |
    > 14 |         const myFunction = (x: number) => x + 1
         |                              ^
      15 |
      16 |         expect(myFunction(3)).toBe(4);
```

I can't understand what's wrong, it looks like jest is treating my source as javascript and not typescript.

Other imformation for completeness is:

1. Compiling with tsc works fine, and the compiled javascript test works correctly and as expected.
2. The same syntax error happens with arrow functions defined outside the scope of 'describe' and 'test' jest functions
3. The same syntax error happens defining the function not as an arrow function but with the 'function' keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in jest configuration.

In order for jest to work it has to transform the code into plain javascript.

One way to accomplish this in a standard and widely used way is to install the package `ts-jest` **and** to initialize its configurations.

(See https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest) for reference.

I followed the following steps:

1. Install ts-jest` and types:

```bash
npm install --save-dev ts-jest 
npm install --save-dev @types/jest
```

2. Create a transform configuration (**key step**, the 'ts-jest' package does not work out of the box on its own):

```bash
npx ts-jest config:init
```

This resulted in the creation of a jest.config.js file:

```js
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

This solved the problem for me.

One side note regarding a subsequent problem that I had:

I had then a problem with tsc because it complained that jest.config.js was not inside the src folder; I simply solved it disallowing js files in my project (`"allowJs": false` in `tsconfig.json`) but it cluld be still an open issue for anyone who needs to use a mix of js/ts inside the project.